# Is it true that IQ and verbal ability are not much correlated?

Tags: iq, speech

I read that people with high IQ are not necessarily good or better speakers or writers. I wonder if that is true.

I read that for instance left-handed people are overrepresented among high IQ people as well as overrepresented among people with verbal and speech problems. Left-handed people are also overrepresented among low IQ people which might explain the verbal and speech problems if that is not adjusted.

Is there any study or evidence supporting any of these claims?

Comment: Have you done any basic googling for these claims? If so would you be so kind as to edit your question and add lonks.